# Permission denied errors after installing AWS CLI on Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

After seeming to succeed in installing the AWS CLI per this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-other-os) I am getting permission denied errors for basic tests while logged in as root on CentOS release 6.6 running python 2.6.6.

```
root@hostname [~]# ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
Running cmd: /usr/bin/python virtualenv.py --python /usr/bin/python /root/.local/lib/aws
Running cmd: /root/.local/lib/aws/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///root/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.10.58.tar.gz
You can now run: /root/bin/aws --version
root@hostname [~]# /root/bin/aws --version
-bash: /root/bin/aws: Permission denied
root@hostname [~]# aws help
-bash: /root/bin/aws: Permission denied
```

**Update**

```
 ls -lZ /root/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx root root ?                                /root/bin/aws -> /root/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws
```

I am a developer with very modest sysadmin knowledge and I don't know my next step.  I wish to be able to automate the storage of website backup tarballs to my S3 buckets from this server.  How do I resolve the permission issues?

**UPDATE 2**
Per suggestion in comments I managed to enable the EPEL repository and install pip following which I appear to have installed aws as before without error BUT I still get permision denied

```
root@hostname [~]# yum install epel-release
[succeeded]
root@hostname [~]# sudo yum install python-pip
[succeeded]
root@hostname [~]# /usr/bin/pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
root@hostname [~]# sudo pip install awscli
[100+ of lines of output]
Successfully installed awscli-1.10.59 botocore-1.4.49 colorama-0.3.7 docutils-0.      12 futures-3.0.5 jmespath-0.9.0 ordereddict-1.1 pyasn1-0.1.9 python-dateutil-2.5      .3 rsa-3.4.2 s3transfer-0.1.2 simplejson-3.3.0 six-1.10.0
root@hostname [~]# which aws
/usr/bin/aws
root@hostname [~]# /usr/bin/aws --version
-bash: /usr/bin/aws: Permission denied
root@hostname [~]# /usr/bin/aws help
-bash: /usr/bin/aws: Permission denied
root@hostname [~]# aws --version
-bash: /usr/bin/aws: Permission denied
root@hostname [~]# aws help
-bash: /usr/bin/aws: Permission denied

root@hostname [~]# ls -lZ /usr/bin/aws
-rw-r--r-- root root ?                                /usr/bin/aws
ls -lZ /usr/bin/ > ~/ls.txt
excerpt from ls.txt:
    -rwxr-xr-x  root root    ?                                auvirt*
    lrwxrwxrwx  root root    ?                                awk -> ../../bin/gawk*
    -rw-r--r--  root root    ?                                aws
    -rw-r--r--  root root    ?                                aws_bash_completer
    -rw-r--r--  root root    ?                                aws.cmd
    -rw-r--r--  root root    ?                                aws_completer
    -rw-r--r--  root root    ?                                aws_zsh_completer.sh
    -rwxr-xr-x  root root    ?                                b43-fwcutter*
    -rwxr-xr-x  root root    ?                                base64*
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what the permissions look like?  `ls -lZ /root/bin/aws`

Comment: @user4556274 added output now

Comment: Try this instead? sudo pip install awscli

Comment: @dmourati Do I need to uninstall and start over using sudo?  Do I need to not be logged in as root doing that?  And `which pip` gives me nothing so I assume I'll need to install it too, right?

Comment: Looks like you tried using pip in the first attempt. To install it, try sudo yum -y install python-pip. I think you've installed previously under /root/bin. You could simply 'rm aws' there and be fine.

Comment: @dmourati I get ` PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found" * rpmforge: mirror.teklinks.com`  `No package python-pip available.`   trying that.

Comment: /usr/local/aws/bin has scripts pip, pip2, and pip2.6

Comment: Got pip installed after enabling EPEL repository

Comment: Run `id -Z` looks as though thats an SELinux thing to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why, but all your aws* commands in /usr/bin don't have execution bit set. Why not try `chmod +x /usr/bin/aws*` and try again?

Comment: Wow, I feel a little foolish... That's solved it.  Thank you.  SO says I have to wait 18 hours to award bounty.  Will add a task in my list for tomorrow.

Comment: I had to issue this command due to symlinks:
chmod +x /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws2